# Basic Integrand Process in R

Tags: r, for-loop, integral, trigonometry

I've been trying to wrap my head around this problem but I am unfortunately quite new to both integrals and R. Can anyone help me figure out what I might be doing wrong here? The problem is as follows:
[Question 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n54OX.png)

Here's my code so far:

```
## Question 3
rm(list=ls())

## a)
X<-(2*(1:20))
X

## b)
Y<-rep(0,20)
Y

## c)
for (k in 1:20){
  Y[k] <- k
  if (k < 12){
    Y[k]<-cos(3*k)
  } else if (k >= 12) {
    integral <- function(t) sqrt(t)
    Y[k]<-integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k)
  }
}
Y
```

Here's my output when I run the code:

```
Warning messages:
1: In Y[k] <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In Y[k] <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In Y[k] <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In Y[k] <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In Y[k] <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
6: In Y[k] <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
7: In Y[k] <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
8: In Y[k] <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
9: In Y[k] <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> Y
[[1]]
[1] -0.9899925

[[2]]
[1] 0.9601703

[[3]]
[1] -0.9111303

[[4]]
[1] 0.843854

[[5]]
[1] -0.7596879

[[6]]
[1] 0.6603167

[[7]]
[1] -0.5477293

[[8]]
[1] 0.424179

[[9]]
[1] -0.2921388

[[10]]
[1] 0.1542514

[[11]]
[1] -0.01327675

[[12]]
[1] 27.71282

[[13]]
[1] 31.24811

[[14]]
[1] 34.92214

[[15]]
[1] 38.72984

[[16]]
[1] 42.66667

[[17]]
[1] 46.72854

[[18]]
[1] 50.91169

[[19]]
[1] 55.21273

[[20]]
[1] 59.62849
```

My values for b) don't seem correct when I use a calculator to check the results and I have no idea why I am receiving the warning for c). I am also unfamiliar with integrals so I have no idea what kind of values I should expect for that problem. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: You might find it helpful to use a simple expression for the integral of t^(1/2) evaluated at the appropriate limits.  The problem does not specifically say that you must use R code to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `integrate(...)`is giving you a `list` as result and you want to replace this in a vector. That´s the error.

```
integral <- function(t) sqrt(t)
result <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = 1)
is(result)
# [1] "integrate" "oldClass" 

result$value
# [1] 0.6666667
```

Here the solution for your problem. Your second line was not necessary.

```
for (k in 1:20){
  if (k < 12){
    Y[k]<-cos(3*k)
  } else if (k >= 12) {
    integral <- function(t) sqrt(t)
    result <- integrate(integral, lower = 0, upper = k)
    Y[k] <- result$value
  }
}
```

Comment: You can mark the answer and vote them up, to show that this solution is right.